# Accelerating artificial gravity station using solar wind

Tags: science-based, space-constructs

In the question [Wind turbines in space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58761/wind-turbines-in-space)

The user asks about using solar wind to rotate turbine like things in order to get energy. Most answers say that using them to get energy would not work because you would need to have a counter rotating turbine and it would be useless, but what if you used the solar wind in that way to accelerate a space station that created artificial gravity using centrifugal force? (I mean using solar wind from the initial acceleration up until the correct speed.) Would this be in any way more efficient that just simply strapping a few rockets onto it?

Comment: Not really, solar wind push will be tiny. Once you get your space station rotating, you don't need any additional push to keep it spinning.

Comment: I am talking about the initial acceleration. You probably would not build the space station while it is spinning, at least in my mind.

Comment: Your entire Space Station is a giant [Crookes Radiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer).  You just need a way to fine tune the speed of rotation, so you absorb just enough energy to compensate for any losses in angular momentum from other sources.

Comment: It would be very impractical to use giant solar sails instead of compact rocket engines. What you can gain by using solar sails is reactionless acceleration, but for rotating space station you'll need to burn your engines just once.

Comment: @cobaltduck The difference is there isn't a fixed axis for a space station. It's going to "roll away" from the star, not spin in place.

Comment: @Alexander makes a good point.  You would only need your solar sails once, to get the spin going.  Then they're a liability that must be either stored or dumped.  You'll occaionally need to make attitude adjustments for which your sails are all but useless.  In other words, you'll need something like [ion thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) anyway, so just use those to get the spin going.

Comment: @Alexander & JBH "for rotating space station you'll need to burn your engines just once." only if you never have visitors, docking & un-docking will effect spin & you'll need to compensate up or down once in a while, docking with a spinning station is also a bitch (remember Elite & trying to dock without a docking computer?) so you may want a hub that doesn't spin to make docking easier,  however that's geared that'll cause friction, this might actually be a nice way to compensate for all that.

Comment: @Pelinore All the best space stations use stationary hubs, as you suggest, to facilitate docking and magnetic levitation to avoid friction.

Comment: @cobaltduck You're right. The Crookes radiometer concept  has promise. A space station may be too massive and time it takes to spin it up could be inordinately long. Also, as Samuel said, there isn't a fixed axis relative to the star & the solar wind. I like the idea even if there are practical problems.

Comment: @cobaltduck - why not float the radiometer concept as an answer here?

Comment: @a4android : I should have said drag instead of ftriction perhaps. even magnetic lev is going to cause some drag on the stations spin surely, & you've got to have a physical connection somewhere to get from the docking hub to the station anyway, however you do it there's going to be an impact on the stations spin.

Comment: On second reading of the link I posted, I realize I was commenting based on incorrect explanation number 1, i.e. light pressure.  This is how I've always believed these toys worked.  Since it seems this is not the correct explanation, that a small amount of gas pressure is involved and they do not work at all in a hard vacuum, then my idea is sunk.  Apologies.  Hopefully we all learned something today- I know I did.

Comment: To get a better idea about practicality, solar wind has pressure 1–6 nPa (1–6×10−9 N/m2) at 1 AU distance. Current ion thrusters generate 25–250 millinewtons. To match one thruster, the sail has be about 30 million square meters, or 30 sq km in size.

Comment: @Pelinore You're right, of course, there will be resistance factors dissipating spin; either friction or drag. Magnetic levitation is probably better, but not perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other said, Solar sails for rotation are not practical, sail will need to be huge, the structure to hold it at correct angle will add to weight, and you will not need nearly as much power once the station is spinning (you will still need a bit to compensate for distortions from landing/launching ships, and people moving inside.

But here is another setup: [The Shkadov thruster](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2013/11/26/moving-stars-the-shkadov-thruster/). 
A giant solar sail, "hovering" above a star as solar wind compensates for gravity pulling it to towards the star. The main effect is the thrust in the direction opposite of the sail, moving the star through space.

But the secondary effect is gravity on the outer (dark) side of the sail.

You can probably have a scaled-down setup where size of the sail is large enough to create gravity for a small station, but not enough to actually move the star.

Comment: Hadn't heard of the Shkadov Thruster before - interesting, thanks.

Comment: You will move the star, even if only slightly. To avoid it, make sail compensate only some % of gravity pull, and take the rest from pseudo-orbital motion. That way you will be moving it in direction that changes constantly, creating little oscillation but no net movement.

Comment: Considering the question wants to spin up a space station for internal centrifugal gravity, building a massive structure to generate gravity for a space station seems unorthodox and more than slightly improbable. Solar-wind powered spin-up would be very, very slow & difficult, but seems more practical by comparison. While I like heroic technological applications, this doesn't seem most practical. Full marks for imagination.

Comment: Thank you. I very much like large, unheard of structures to do things that I ask about. I remember hearing about something like this, I even saw that picture of the website, but I never knew what it was and what it could do. Once again, thank you. 
Sidenote: The website also says that it has the capability to move the planets along with the star. Wouldn't the thruster create an artificial night and day on tidally locked planets as well?